# How to perform an action when a process has finished, whilst there are multiple processes are running

Tags: php, python, process

I'm making a scan server for my company, which will be used to launch scans from tools such as nessus, nmap, nikto etc. I've written the pages in php, so once the scan is launched it backgrounds the process and returns the PID. Part of the design spec is that once a scan has finished, the results are then emailed to the appropiate consultant. This is where I'm looking for some ideas, for I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Would I be best making the php script feed the PID to instances of a python (my main language) script, which constantly checked to see if the process had finished, for example? I did try putting this process checking loop in the PHP page, but obviously this makes the PHP page pause whilst it waits for the scan to complete, which doesn't work for me unfortunately as multiple scans will be being run.

Or would I be better creating a database which stored state information about the process? I have no database experience but this could be a good time to learn.

Any suggestions? Even some ideas that I can google would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I face this kind of problem, I usually do a Python daemon that does the whole job, and have the PHP just sending messages to this Python daemon. These messages can be something very simple, like a bunch of files in a directory that is constantly checked, or registers in database.

How good this implmeentation is would depend on the scale of your application.

Comment: I had not even considered a python daemon. Interesting! I shall look into it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are starting the processes something like this:

```
exec("/path/to/file > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

...in which case, you can just put another script in the middle:

```
exec("/path/to/file | php /some/php/script.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Then, in `script.php` (or do it in python if you want), you can do something like this:

```
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
  sleep(1); // ...or something less horrible that also avoids racing
}

// When you get here, the process has finished
```

Comment: Only problem is it creates *even more* processes... which if you are doing a lot of them at once could eat server resources.

Comment: Thanks for help - that is code I'm using to start the processes btw. It does seem like a good idea, but as you say creating even more processes might be an issue. I think I also need to implement some code that checks to make sure that no more than x amount of processes are running that originated from the scan page. Would it be possible to incorporate that into the PHP code?

Comment: It's probably possible, but difficult. How long do the processes usually run for? It seems like you might be better with a daemon if you want to do this - where the PHP page would communicate to the daemon that it's time to start a process, and the daemon would track the processes and handle the email sending (much like @lfagundes has suggested)

Comment: Ah well some processes could be running for 20 minutes plus if it's a large IP range. In that case I'll look into coding a daemon then. Thanks a lot for all the help!